# How to add thousand comma seperator for values in ggplotly's hover option

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the following chart created in R using `ggplot2` and `plotly`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(Values = c(1000, 2000, 3000), Category = c('one', 'two', 'three'))

p <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = Values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') 

p %>% ggplotly()
```

Is there any way I can format the Values in the hover information to have a thousand comma seperator? So for example, the number `1000` to appear as `1 000` or `1,000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `text` aesthetic and making use of `scales::number` or `scales::comma` this could be achieved like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(Values = c(1000, 2000, 3000), Category = c('one', 'two', 'three'))

p <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = Values, text = paste("Values:", scales::number(Values)))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') 

p %>% ggplotly(tooltip = c("x", "text"))
```

[image]